# how to get JSON from string variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

### My json is following

> ```
> {"d":
>    {"__type":"HPROffice.Fault","status":"ok","message":"Record 
>    exist","Details":null,"First":"{\"status\" : \"OK\", 
>     data : [{\"uid\":1,\"groupname\":\"SK   Softlab\", \"ownername\": \"Santosh\",
> ```
>
> \"mobile\":\"9982598102\",\"mobile2\":null,\"savetime\":\"\/Date(1501353000000)\/\",\"status\":true,\"extra\":null,\"saveby\":1,\"updateby\":null,\"updatetime\":null,\"openingbalance\":5000}]
>       }","Second":null,"Third":null,"Fourth":null,"Fifth":null}
>       }

and am trying this

```
function loaddata(grpid)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "managegroup.aspx/LoadGroup",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{grpid:" + grpid + "}",
                success: function (response) {
                    //alert("called");
                    var jsonobj = response.d;
                    if (jsonobj.status == "ok") {
                        Clear();
                        alert(jsonobj.First);
                        var json = JSON.parse(jsonobj.First);
                        //var json = $.parseJSON("'"+jsonobj.First+"'");
                        alert(json.status);

                    }
                    else {
                        $("#msg").css("color", "red");
                    }
                    $("#msg").text(response.d.message);
                },
                error: function (response) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What is your question? Please edit the question, format it properly and explain what you're trying to do, what isn't working etc.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your question you're asking how you can convert a json string to a json object. If this is correct check out the following.

```
JSON.parse('{"mobile\":\"9982598102\",\"mobile2\":null}');
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: @SKYogi did this help?

Comment: i want convert to json value of First field but problem is that its a string variable so JSON.parse and $.parseJSON is not working